# Аналог дружественных методов в Python

Tags: python, ооп

Имеется такой код:

```
class BinVector(object):
    def __init__(self, size_=8):
        self.size = size_
        self._vector = bytearray(size_//8 + 1)

    def __and__(self, other):
        if self.size != other.size:
            raise Exception("this is unacceptable!!")
        res = BinVector(self.size)
        for i in range(self.size//8 + 1):
            res._vector[i] = self._vector[i] & other._vector[i] #здесь предупреждение
        return res
```

Мой PyCharm выдает предупреждение, так как self._vector есть защищенное поле.
Есть ли в Python дружественные методы, или лучше оставить все как есть, или лучше сделать self.vector публичным?

Comment: Нету, но предупреждение-то выдаёт тоже не Python, так что я бы его проигнорировал и оставил бы как есть

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что `self._vector` ни разу не `private`? Эта переменная вообще никак не ограничена к доступу, отличается от обычной только способом вызова из импортируемого модуля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подчеркивание в начале подразумевает, что данный член предполагается "для внутреннего использования". Сам интерпретатор ничего не ограничивает (нет в Питоне приватных членов!), а вот уже PyCharm не будет выдавать такой член в подсказке после точки у объекта этого класса.

При этом в методах самого класса такое предупреждение, возможно, избыточно.